# Delphi TList<T> Copy into another TList?

Tags: delphi, tlist

I would like to know if there is any safe way to copy the TList elements into any other TList to a 
specific position and with a specific length. Should I just assign the elements of the list1 to list2 or 
is there any functionality out there I'm not aware of that handles that more accurate?

Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your intention is to **REPLACE** items rather than to insert them at a given position, then the answer is that there is no direct mechanism and iterative assignment is the approach to use.

```
for i := 1 to maxItems do
  dest[ insertPos + i - 1] := src[ i - 1 ];
```

In this case you should consider the situation where you are adding more items than the destination list has room for.  Whether this means only replacing as many items as will "fit", adding additional items to 'make room' or not assigning any at all (unless all will fit), is a question that only your requirements can answer.

However, if your intention is to **INSERT** the items into the destination list, then you can use a combination of **InsertRange()** and **Copy()** together with the internal **array of <T>** maintained by the source list.  For example, using two instances of a **TList<String>**:

```
var
  src, dest: TList<String>;
  insertIndex, maxItems: Integer;

dest.InsertRange( insertIndex, Copy( src.List, 0, maxItems ) );
```

To insert the *entire* **src** list you do not need to use **Copy()** but can reference the source list directly in the **InsertRange()** method:

```
dest.InsertRange( insertIndex, src );
```

**Performance Notes:**

The use of **Copy()** is a potentially expensive operation if the source list is large and/or the number of sub-items being added is small.  However, the actual insertion of the items into the destination list is very efficient as the **InsertRange()** method is able to make room for the new items in the destination list in a single operation and then insert the new items in the space created for them, so for larger numbers of items being added it may still prove to be the most efficient.

The alternative approach would be to iteratively insert the source items individually:

```
for i := 1 to maxItems do
  dest.Insert( insertIndex, src[i - 1]);
```

Whilst this avoids copying array items being inserted, inserting iteratively is itself potentially inefficient if the destination list is large and a larger number of items are being inserted, as room for each item in the destination list has to be made separately for each insert (although the potential impact of this may be significantly improved by explicitly calculating and pre-allocating the **Capacity** of the destination list).

e.g. if you are inserting 100 items from a 1000 item list into the (exact) middle of a 2000 item list:

```
InsertRange( Copy() )       Copy 100 items into an intermediate array
                            Moves 1000 items in the dest list to make room for 2100 (total)
                            Inserts 100 items into the 'blank' space

Iterative insert            100 repetitions of:
                               Move 1000 items in the dest list to make room for 1 more
                               Inserts 1 item
```

For inserting 100 items, **InsertRange()** is potentially the most efficient.  By contrast, if inserting only a single item from the source list then the **InsertRange()** approach incurs a potentially excessive overhead.

As I think should be obvious, different starting conditions would determine which of the two approaches is the most efficient, and should be considered if performance is a significant concern.

Comment: ToArray would be expensive especially if the list was large and only a few elements were to be copied. The `List` property would avoid the need to call ToArray.

Comment: OP was clearly aware of the ability to simply insert items iteratively.  The question was whether there was existing functionality as an alternative.  Inserting iteratively involves multiple memory copies to make room in the destination list for each item separately which itself could be very expensive if the destination is large.  InsertRange() with a copied array inserts the items in "builk".  I do not think there is a "one size fits all" approach that is certain to be the most optimal.  Better to be aware of the options.  Answer will be updated to explain these options.

Comment: Also noted and addressed the ambiguity in the question w.r.t inserting items or replacing them.  Answer previously only addressed the insertion case.  I updated to address the replacement case also.

Comment: Sorry to go on, but ToArray is always a mistake here. Use `TList<T>.List` instead and avoid the copy.

Comment: Quite right... Bonus:  with that change, there is even more performance advantage vs iterative inserts for large # of sub-items.  :)

Answer (score 6):

I would use [AddRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.AddRange) for append Items on the end or [InsertRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.InsertRange) to insert Items on a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Enny, `Assign` copies from the destination list (clearing the contents of the source list).

```
list1 := TList.Create();
for val:=1 to 3 do
    list1.Add(Pointer(val));    // list1 contains {1,2,3}

list2 := TList.Create();
for val:=5 to 8 do
    list2.Add(Pointer(val));    // list2 contains {5,6,7,8}

list2.Assign(list1);            // list2 now contains {1,2,3}
list2.Assign(list1);            // list2 still contains {1,2,3}

list2.Free();
list1.Free();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that both lists are generic `TList<T>`. And that you are copying over existing items rather than extending the destination.

In which case, I think a `for` loop with an assignment using `:=` is the way to go. Since you are dealing with a generic list you need to use an operator that can work with any generic type `T`. Assuming you need to support `T` that is a managed type then you cannot perform a simple memory copy. That leaves you with assignment.